# how to detect if user clicked done or open after application in android has been installed programmatically

Tags: android, file, apk

I'm having trouble detecting if the user clicked the dialog, that usually pops up after the android application has been installed. So that I can proceed to the next installation or activity.

Comment: What do you mean? What dialogue box are we talking about here ?

Comment: a dialogue box that informs user that application has been installed, there are two buttons at the bottom of it, "Open" and "Done". I need to know if one of the buttons has been clicked.

Comment: How would you wan't to capture done? It doesn't belong to your process....

Comment: yes, any of the two buttons, because after installing the first application, i have to install the remaining apk file.

Comment: or even how to hide them at least.

Comment: Did you create the dialog yourself or is it something that the Android system inflates?

Comment: it is from android. After installation, that certain dialog box will appear.

Comment: Just look at this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422364/installing-a-list-of-apk-automatically-and-programmatically

Comment: Just look at this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422364/installing-a-list-of-apk-automatically-and-programmatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422364/installing-a-list-of-apk-automatically-and-programmatically... Just look at this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get you correctly,

- You are trying to programatically install a APK
- You need to get the status, whether the user pressed buttons `Open` or `Done`, after the successful installation.

This can be done. For this, start the package installer like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(
Uri.fromFile(new File("Full path to your APK")),
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive"); // the APK path can be in SDCARD or in your application directory. I am sure you know this path.

// start the package-installer activity and wait for result. The second parameter can be used to identify the source of result in `onActivityResult` method. 
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

- Now the package installer will be started and your APK will get installed on device.
- User presses either `Open` or `Done` buttons.
- You gets the program control back in `onActivityResult` callback function

Here goes the `onActivityResult` function:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // requestCode == 1 means the result for package-installer activity
    if (requestCode == 1) 
    {
        // resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED means user pressed `Done` button
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "User pressed 'Done' button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // resultCode == RESULT_OK means user pressed `Open` button
            Toast.makeText(this, "User pressed 'Open' button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: oh! i'll try this, because i've been also wondering what the resultCode is in the onActivityResult function. I'll get back to you if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I tried your code, but it still not working, i believe it worked in confirmation dialog before installing the application, in which it asked you to install or not the app. but not after being installed. should i add setresult(RESULT_OK) after startActivityForResult() function?

Answer (score 2):

You can't detect that.

If you are wanting to do some operation on the first run of the application then just store a "first run" flag within your user preferences and default it to true.

You can then check this on start of your app and perform any necessary operations.

Some example code for this;

```
private boolean prefFirstRun;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    prefFirstRun= settings.getBoolean("FirstRun", true);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (prefFirstRun) {
        prefFirstRun = false;
        // Do your initial operations here
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("FirstRun", false);
    editor.commit();

}
```

Comment: can you elaborate where will i continue the second activity or second install?

Comment: In this example I have put the check for First Run on the onStart method but you could perform this check anywhere within your  application.

Comment: to get the desired result, I combined your answer and the answer above. I learned that when the activity is finished, the oncreate() function is called again, so the onActivityResult() function is not working properly. I tried to let the onCreate() function execute once, and continue installing the rest of the apk's in the onActivityResult() function instead