# Installing a list of APK automatically and programmatically

Tags: android

I have a list of APK and it should be installed automatically.

here's my current situation.

- first APK appears, Install or Cancel
- user clicks install
- a windows appears and will ask the user to "open" or "done"
- but the problem is, after that window appears to choose "open" or
  "done", the next APK installation window appears and covering the
  "open" or "done" window of the first successful APK installed.

How do you buffer that the next APK to install shall wait till the user chooses "open" or "done" after the first installation.

currently i'm trying out these methods but to no avail :(

```
 protected void onStart();

 protected void onRestart();

 protected void onResume();

 protected void onPause();

 protected void onStop();

 protected void onDestroy();
```

can anyone point out the right direction? i'm still new to this.

thanks!

Comment: you mean install more than one apk at same time?

Comment: not really, not on the same time but one at a time.

Comment: Not possible. You can check if user Cancels or the installation is done. [Similar issue with you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403535/how-to-detect-if-user-clicked-done-or-open-after-application-in-android-has-been)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not possible... You can only launch an `Intent` to install an apk but you can't be sure if the apk is installed (If he comes back as if he clicks on open after installation, he doesn't come back).

---

But, in your `Activity`, the `onResume` method is called when the user comes back to your application.

You can at this moment check if the 1st apk is installed and launch the 2nd apk installation.